# Need to use `IN` for multiple string value in static query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, static

```
SELECT * 
FROM #empInfo 
WHERE source IN (CASE WHEN @source = 'Mint' THEN 'Mint, Ming' ELSE @source END)
```

I am trying in the way as above.

```
CREATE TABLE #empInfo
(
     id INT IDENTITY(1, 1), 
     ename VARCHAR(50), 
     source VARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO #empInfo 
VALUES ('Jon', 'Mint'), ('Jack', 'Ryan'), ('Jackie', 'Ming'),
       ('Jeny', 'Wing'), ('Jen', 'Wing')

DECLARE @source VARCHAR(50)
SET @source = 'Mint'
```

From the above what if want is, if the value `Mint` comes in the `@source` then it has to search for `Mint,Ming` else what comes in `@source`. `@source` always hold single value.

I have to apply this logic in very large query which is not dynamic nor I can make it, so please provide me the solution for this case if any.

Sorry, if it's not possible without dynamic query.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM #empInfo 
WHERE (@source = 'Mint' and source in ('Mint','Ming'))
   OR (@source <> 'Mint' and source = @source)
```

Remember that an `IN` clause needs separate string values. So you can't use a comma separated list in `@source`

A shorter version of the above query would be

```
SELECT * FROM #empInfo 
WHERE @source = source
   OR (@source = 'Mint' and source  = 'Ming')
```

Comment: Appreciate your answer but getting syntax error, is there something missing ?

Comment: Try again please and add the error if it still does not work

Comment: I tried it and ddnt get any error, review your code, perhaps you dropped some quote or something

Comment: Really elegant, Thank you very much !